# How to display only words with parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to display only words which begin with capital letters and are build only from letters in the same time. My code shows full sentences.

```
egrep -wo '\b[A-Z]\w[a-z A-Z]*' ./lipsum.txt|uniq
```

File contains text lorem ipsum

Comment: Please [edit] your question, show some example input, the actual output you get and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a space in the bracket expression, so you're telling grep that space is a character you want. Try

```sh
grep -Ewo '[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]*' file | sort -u
```

Note that `egrep` is deprecated: use `grep -E`

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

`grep '\<[A-Z][A-Za-z]*\>' file`